# Intel SSD with USB 3

Tags: ssd, usb-3

I have an Intel 520 SSD that I had wanted to use to speed a few things up. I'm using it on a gateway all in one with Windows 7 and there doesn't seem to be room for another drive inside.

There are 2 USB3 ports, one of which I am using for a backup Hard drive and the other was to be used for the SSD. I installed the drive into an external USB 3 box but Windows will not recognize it. It works fine with the USB 2 ports but what's the point? Will this drive work as a USB drive with a SATA to USB box?

Comment: Does the drive show up in Device Manager?  It's possible the USB3 Host device has trouble reading the existing partition.  It also might be a dynamic volume that is marked as foreign and must be imported.  You can do so in Disk Management.  But first check to see if the drive shows up and let me know what you see.

Comment: Does it do _anything_ when you plug it into the USB3 ports? Do other devices work in those USB3 ports?  Do you have up-to-date drivers installed for the USB3 controller?